# npm completion broken

Tags: zsh, nodejs, npm

I'm running `npm 1.2.18` and `node v0.10.15`.  `npm completion` is broken.  If I try to tab complete with `npm` or if I run `npm completion`, it displays:

```
npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-14-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "completion" "--color" "false" "--loglevel" "error" "--" "npm" "comple"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ajcrites
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! path /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/completion.sh
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
```

Indeed, `/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/completion.sh` does not exist, and the current directory gets an `npm-debug.log` file with similar information.

A [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=npm%20completion%20zsh&oq=npm%20completion&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l2.4338j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) reveals a lot of complaints about this issue for varying versions of node/Debian/zsh.  If I use bash, tab completion works, but `npm completion` yields the same error about the missing file.  As far as I can tell, none of the threads that you can easiliy find from the search actually have a solution.  They just seem to be bug reports.

Is there anything I can do to fix this error?  Is there an example `completion.sh` I can use or something?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by using: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/npm-completion.1.html

Specifically I took the following file: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages.gz/oneiric/man1/npm-completion.1.gz

And extracted it to:

```
/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/completion.sh
```

After restarting the console, **npm in** would complete to **npm install**!

Comment: bash: /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/completion.sh: Permission denied

Comment: `sudo chmod +x /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/completion.sh`